# Room update query that checks if a column contains a certain string from a list<string>

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-room

In my Channels entity there are among others two attributes: `val name: String and val editedName: String`. "name" is the original name from the server, editedName (is initially = name)
would then be the name edited by the user based on their entered prefixes and suffixes, which I store in the PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting entity: `val prefixes: List<String> and val suffixes: List<String>`.

Example:

1. name = ABC TestChannel XZ
2. name = ABC TestChannel VW
3. name = 123 Test XY
4. name = Test VW
5. name = A TestChannel Xy

val prefixes = "ABC"; "A"
val suffixes = "XZ"; "VW"

1. editedName = TestChannel
2. editedName = TestChannel
3. editedName = 123 Test XY
4. editedName = Test
5. editedName = TestChannel XY

The editedName should always take into account the current prefixes and suffixes list and be updated accordingly.

For example, if the user removes "XZ" from the list of suffixes, the 1st editedName changes to TestChannel XZ.

At the moment I use a function in which I get all channels from the database and then check each channel with a loop for the presence of a prefix or suffix and remove it if there are:

```
    suspend fun updatePrefixesAndSuffixes(prefixes: List<String>, suffixes: List<String>) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _nameProcessState.value = ChannelNameProcessState.Loading
            val allChannels = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                dao.getAllChannels()
            }
            _nameProcessState.value = ChannelNameProcessState.GetChannels(100)
            val editedChannels = allChannels.map { channel ->
                var modifiedName = channel.name
                prefixes.forEach { prefix ->
                    if (modifiedName.startsWith(prefix)) {
                        modifiedName = modifiedName.removePrefix(prefix).trim()
                    }
                }
                _nameProcessState.value = ChannelNameProcessState.DatabaseInsertion(50)
                suffixes.forEach { suffix ->
                    if (modifiedName.endsWith(suffix)) {
                        modifiedName = modifiedName.removeSuffix(suffix).trim()
                    }
                }
                _nameProcessState.value = ChannelNameProcessState.DatabaseInsertion(100)
                channel.copy(editedName = modifiedName)
            }

            // Update the edited channels in the database
            dao.updateChannels(editedChannels)
            _nameProcessState.value = ChannelNameProcessState.Success
        }
    }
```

The function works. However, I would like to make the process a little more efficient and with less memory-usage, as I have problems with out of memory crashes every now and then,
when I open channel lists in another fragment while running this function.

I have therefore tried to create an UPDATE query that should work as follows:
it checks each channel of the Channels entity if:

1. a prefix from the prefixes: List AND a suffix from the suffixes: List is present in "name" of the channel -> if yes, it sets the editedName = name without the found prefix AND suffix.
2. if 1. is not true, it checks if a prefix from the prefixes: List OR a suffix from the suffixes: List is present in "name" of the channel -> if yes, it sets then editedName = name without the found prefix OR suffix.
3. if 1. and 2. is not true the editedName is kept as it is.

```
    @Query("UPDATE channels SET editedName = " +
            "CASE " +
            "WHEN name LIKE '%' || :prefixes || '%' AND name LIKE '%' || :suffixes || '%' " +
            "     THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(name, :prefixes, ''), :suffixes, '') " +
            "WHEN name LIKE '%' || :prefixes || '%' " +
            "     THEN REPLACE(name, :prefixes, '') " +
            "WHEN name LIKE '%' || :suffixes || '%' " +
            "     THEN REPLACE(name, :suffixes, '') " +
            "ELSE editedName " +
            "END")
    suspend fun updateChannelsWithPrefixesAndSuffixes(prefixes: List<String>, suffixes: List<String>)
```

The problem, as I understand, is that prefixes and suffixes are a list, if prefixes and suffixes were single strings it would theoretically work.

Is there any possibility, with the help of a query, to perform my desired check? Or do I have to encapsulate this somehow?

Can one of the Room / SQLite experts here help me or give me a hint how this could possibly be done, or should I just stick with my current function?

Answer (score 0):

***Warning quite a long-winded answer** (2 actually)*

First issue/complication is that the `A` prefix would result in `ABC TestChannel VW`, if not already altered in the editedname becoming `BC TestChnnel VW`.

- Assuming that prefixes have a trailing space then suffixing the prefix with a space would circumvent this, likewise prefixing a suffix with a space would circumvent the similar being applied for suffixes, assuming that there is always a leading space for a suffix.
- without trailing/leading space (or another delimiter) then there would be greater potential for inadvertent changes.

  - REGEXP might be more apt **BUT* I believe that it is not available (it's not a default built-in, so a special build of SQLite may be required).

The next issue is that the CASEs will likely not cover all permutations of prefix and suffix. This does assume that suffixes and prefixes are not paired , which appears to be the case.

In short you are moving into a quite complex area. It would be far easier, if possible, to split the name into 3 columns:-

- name for the name less any prefix or suffix (pretty simple to do if a space delimits the 3 components)
- prefix for the the prefix part (could be an empty string)
- suffix for the suffix part (could be an empty string)

Otherwise, by the looks of it you may have to deal with numerous permutations.

- As PrefixesAndSuffixesSettings is an Entity, the implication, is that it is  a table. If the table has a row per prefix or suffix and and indicator of which then it is relatively simply to build a list of all permutations of prefix and suffix.

**Another Solution**

This solution (or the basis of a solution) uses an intermediate class to split the prefix and suffix (if any) via a primary constructor, that takes:-

- a Channels,
- an optional Separator (default a space)
- a List for each for the prefixes and also the suffixes.
- An assumption has been made that they are not paired but prefixes and suffixes have a row each and that an indicator is used to differentiate.

The class has a function that can return a Channels object.

So in short a Channel and the two list is used to construct an object, doing the editing (actually splitting prefix and suffix) as part of the construction, and can return a Channel object with the the name built from the prefix + name (edited) + suffix

- both prefix and/or suffix can be an empty string.

As such the Class can be used to either drive updates or when inserting a Channels (individually). The following is a demonstration of both:-

First the demo is based upon the an interpretation of the tables i.e. the `@Entity` annotated classes as per:-

```
@Entity
data class Channels(
    @PrimaryKey
    val name: String,
    val editedName: String = name
)
@Entity
data class PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Long?=null,
    val fix: String,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "false")
    val isAPrefix: Boolean
)
```

- obviously changes may be required to suit the actual classes.

The All Important intermediate class is, possibly for the want of a more apt name, **AltChannels** as per:-

```
class AltChannels(
    c: Channels,
    sep: String = " ",
    prefixes: List<PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting>,
    suffixes: List<PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting>
) {
    var name: String=""
    var prefix: String=""
    var suffix: String=""

    init {
        var pflag = false
        var sflag = false
        this.name = c.name
        for (p in prefixes) {
            if (c.name.contains(p.fix + sep)) {
                this.name = this.name.replace(p.fix + sep,"")
                this.prefix = p.fix
                pflag = true
            }
        }
        for (s in suffixes) {
            if (c.name.contains(sep + s.fix)) {
                this.name = this.name.replace(sep + s.fix,"")
                this.suffix = s.fix
                sflag = true
            }
        }
        if (!pflag && !sflag) this.name = c.name
        Log.d("DBINFO_CONSTR","Constructed AC where:-\n\tName is $name\n\tPrefix is $prefix\n\tSuffix is $suffix")
    }

    fun getChannelsWithResolvedEditedName(sep: String = " "): Channels {
        val rv = Channels(name = this.prefix + sep + this.name + sep + this.suffix, editedName = this.name)
        Log.d("DBINFO_GCWEN","Returning Channel FROM AC Where:-" +
                "\n\tAC Name is ${this.name}" +
                "\n\tAC Prefix is ${this.prefix}" +
                "\n\tAC Suffix is ${this.suffix}" +
                "\n\tCHNL Name is ${rv.name}" +
                "\n\tCHNL EDITED is ${rv.editedName}")
        return rv
    }
}
```

- Logging included for debugging and should obviously be removed.
- There are other changes that can be made to reduce the code from a debugging version, such as directly returning the resolved Channels object.

  - i.e. the code is very much development code.

To support the demo the following `@Dao` interface:-

```
@Dao
interface AllDAOs {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(channels: Channels): Long
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun insert(prefixesAndSuffixesSetting: PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting WHERE isAPrefix")
    fun getPrefixes(): List<PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting WHERE NOT isAPrefix")
    fun getSuffixes(): List<PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting>
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Channels")
    fun getAllChannels(): List<Channels>

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    fun updateChannel(channels: Channels): Int

    @Transaction
    @Query("") /* Dummy Query to fool Room into understanding that it can wrap a transaction around the function */
    fun resolveAllChannelEditedNames() {
        val prefixes = getPrefixes()
        val suffixes = getSuffixes()
        for (c in getAllChannels()) {
            var ac = AltChannels(c,prefixes = prefixes, suffixes = suffixes)
            //updateChannel(ac.getChannelsWithResolvedEditedName()) bug so commented out
            val result = updateChannel(Channels(c.name,ac.name)) //<<<<< correction
        }
    }
}
```

A basic/simple `@Database` annotated abstract class to put it all together, noting the use of `.allowMainThreadQueries` for brevity/convenience:-

Finally the Activity code for the demo (intended only for a fresh (new install) single run) :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDAOs
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDAOs()

        /* Load the testing data */
        dao.insert(Channels("ABC TestChannel XZ"))
        dao.insert(Channels("ABC TestChannel VW"))
        dao.insert(Channels("123 Test XY"))
        dao.insert(Channels("Test VW"))
        dao.insert(Channels("A TestChannel Xy"))

        dao.insert(PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting(fix ="ABC", isAPrefix = true))
        dao.insert(PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting(fix ="A", isAPrefix = true))
        dao.insert(PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting(fix ="XZ", isAPrefix = false))
        dao.insert(PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting(fix ="VW", isAPrefix = false))

        /* Get the prefixes and suffixes */
        val ps = dao.getPrefixes()
        val ss = dao.getSuffixes()

        /* Load another Channels Row pre resolving the prefix and suffix */
        val cBase = AltChannels(Channels("ABC TestChannelOther VW"), prefixes = ps, suffixes = ss).getChannelsWithResolvedEditedName()
        dao.insert(cBase)

        /* Show the loaded data before update */
        logAllChannels("STAGE1")
        /* Update/Resolve All the channels */
        dao.resolveAllChannelEditedNames()
        /* Show the post resolve data */
        logAllChannels("STAGE2")
    }

    fun logAllChannels(tagSuffix: String) {
        val TAG = "DBINFO"
        for (c in dao.getAllChannels())  {
            Log.d("${TAG}_${tagSuffix}","Channel is ${c.name} EditedName is ${c.editedName}")
        }
    }
}
```

**Demo Result**

The log, when the above is run for a fresh install, includes:-

```
2023-09-01 13:41:26.122 D/DBINFO_STAGE1: Channel is ABC TestChannel XZ EditedName is ABC TestChannel XZ
2023-09-01 13:41:26.122 D/DBINFO_STAGE1: Channel is ABC TestChannel VW EditedName is ABC TestChannel VW
2023-09-01 13:41:26.122 D/DBINFO_STAGE1: Channel is 123 Test XY EditedName is 123 Test XY
2023-09-01 13:41:26.122 D/DBINFO_STAGE1: Channel is Test VW EditedName is Test VW
2023-09-01 13:41:26.122 D/DBINFO_STAGE1: Channel is A TestChannel Xy EditedName is A TestChannel Xy
2023-09-01 13:41:26.122 D/DBINFO_STAGE1: Channel is ABC TestChannelOther VW EditedName is TestChannelOther


2023-09-01 18:05:45.172 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is ABC TestChannel XZ EditedName is TestChannel
2023-09-01 18:05:45.172 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is ABC TestChannel VW EditedName is TestChannel
2023-09-01 18:05:45.172 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is 123 Test XY EditedName is 123 Test XY
2023-09-01 18:05:45.172 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is Test VW EditedName is Test
2023-09-01 18:05:45.172 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is A TestChannel Xy EditedName is TestChannel Xy
2023-09-01 18:05:45.172 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is ABC TestChannelOther VW EditedName is TestChannelOther
2023-09-01 18:05:45.172 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is ABC TextChannelOther VW EditedName is TextChannelOther
```

- *Note timestamps differ due to bug being found and fixed (`A TestChannel Xy` was not updating due to a discrepancy between the name passed and the actual name change to the `resolveAllChannelEditedNames` function is commented upon in the code)*
- As can be Stage1 shows all names the same as the edited name **EXCEPT** for the row that was inserted using the resolution via the AltChannels as per `dao.insert(AltChannels(Channels(name = "ABC TextChannelOther VW"), prefixes = ps, suffixes = ss).getChannelsWithResolvedEditedName())` *rewritten to insert directly rather than via the Cbase*
- Stage 2, without comprehensive checking, has resolved/changed the **editedNames** in line with the requirement of the question.

Even though this appears to be similar to your approach, the work is undertaken as a single transaction and will therefore very likely be less time consuming. Again you may wish to consider resolving the editedName when inserting, thus averting the need to do bulk updates.

---

**QUERY ONLY SOLUTION** *(Warning quite complex)*

---

It is very likely feasible that the goal could be accomplished via a [WITH clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_with.html) (an `WITH .... UPDATE`) this would be quite complex in itself, let alone then adapting it to use via a room query (maintenance could be a nightmare). However, using a recursive query, could well faster and possibly less memory intensive.

The following (minimal testing) uses this technique:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("WITH " +
        "prefixes(prowid,p) AS (SELECT rowid,fix FROM PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting WHERE isAPrefix)," +
        "suffixes(srowid,s) AS (SELECT rowid,fix FROM PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting WHERE NOT isAPrefix)," +
        "perms(prowid,p,srowid,s) AS (SELECT prowid,p,srowid,s FROM prefixes JOIN suffixes)," +
        "potentials AS (" +
        "SELECT " +
        "name," +
        "replace(replace(name,p||' ',''),' '||s,'') AS editedName, " +
        "length(replace(replace(name,p||' ',''),' '||s,'')) AS l, " +
        "p AS prefix, " +
        "s AS suffix " +
        "FROM channels " +
        "JOIN perms " +
        "WHERE instr(name,p||' ') OR instr(name,' '||s) " +
        "ORDER BY name ASC , l DESC" +
        ")" +
        "UPDATE channels " +
        "SET editedName = (" +
        "SELECT editedname " +
        "FROM potentials " +
        "WHERE potentials.name = channels.name AND potentials.l = (" +
        "SELECT min(l) FROM potentials AS p WHERE potentials.name = p.name)" +
        ") " +
        "WHERE channels.name IN(SELECT name FROM potentials);"
)
fun resolveCEN()
```

- ***Note** `@Transaction` is not required as it is all a single execution. (i.e. a single transaction anyway)*

It consists of 4 CTEs:-

- **prefixes** is a CTE with the prefixes (prowid is superfluous)
- **suffixies** is a CTE with the suffixes (srowid is also superfluous)
- **perms** is all permutations of prefixes and suffixes
- **potentials** is list of the updates to be applied (name and editedName) that is used to drive the updates. It results in (when applied to your data, rather than the data as per the App which contains an additional row for `ABC TestChannelOther VW`):-

[image]

```
- column **l** is used for the selection of the update that has the shortest editedName per name.
- prefix and suffix columns were included for debugging and are superfluous
```

- The final code is the UPDATE that utilises the **potentials** CTE aka what is done with the WITH.

When `resolveCEN()` is used in the App when run from a fresh install, and replaces the previous resolve function, as per this change to the code:-

```
    //dao.resolveAllChannelEditedNames()
    dao.resolveCEN() //<<<<<<<< CTE based
```

The resultant STAGE2 output to the log is:-

```
2023-09-01 21:01:57.324 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is ABC TestChannel XZ EditedName is TestChannel
2023-09-01 21:01:57.325 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is ABC TestChannel VW EditedName is TestChannel
2023-09-01 21:01:57.325 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is 123 Test XY EditedName is 123 Test XY
2023-09-01 21:01:57.325 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is Test VW EditedName is Test
2023-09-01 21:01:57.325 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is A TestChannel Xy EditedName is TestChannel Xy
2023-09-01 21:01:57.325 D/DBINFO_STAGE2: Channel is ABC TestChannelOther VW EditedName is TestChannelOther
```

**Note**

The query was put together using an SQLite tool (Navicat) of which there are quite a few (e.g. DBeaver, DB Browser for SQLite, SQLiteStudio). This is the recommended approach.

The resultant SQL can then be copied and pasted between the double quotes of the String and then edited to remove the tabs and line feeds.

This is the SQL used to develop this (which can be dropped into such tools):-

```
/* just in case environment cleanup */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS channels;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting;
/* Create the tables */
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS channels (name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, editedName TEXT);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting (fix TEXT PRIMARY KEY, isAPrefix INTEGER DEFAULT 0);
/* Load test data into the tables */
INSERT INTO channels VALUES 
    ('ABC TestChannel XZ','ABC TestChannel XZ'),
    ('ABC TestChannel VW','ABC TestChannel VW'),
    ('123 Test XY','123 Test XY'),
    ('Test VW','Test VW'),('A TestChannel Xy','A TestChannel Xy');
INSERT INTO PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting
    VALUES('ABC',1),('A',1),('XZ',0),('VW',0);
    
/* Show it (initial testing to develop the CTE's using a) i.e. WITH .... SELECT*/
WITH 
    prefixes(prowid,p) AS (SELECT rowid,fix FROM PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting WHERE isAPrefix),
    suffixes(srowid,s) AS (SELECT rowid,fix FROM PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting WHERE NOT isAPrefix),
    perms(prowid,p,srowid,s) AS (SELECT prowid,p,srowid,s FROM prefixes JOIN suffixes),
    potentials AS (
        SELECT name,replace(replace(name,p||' ',''),' '||s,'') AS editedName, length(replace(replace(name,p||' ',''),' '||s,'')) AS l, p AS prefix, s AS suffix FROM channels JOIN perms WHERE instr(name,p||' ') OR instr(name,' '||s) ORDER BY name ASC , l DESC)
SELECT * FROM potentials;
/* Show the channels prior to the update */
SELECT * FROM channels;
 /* After developing the core CTE's work on the WITH UPDATE */
WITH 
    prefixes(prowid,p) AS (SELECT rowid,fix FROM PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting WHERE isAPrefix),
    suffixes(srowid,s) AS (SELECT rowid,fix FROM PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting WHERE NOT isAPrefix),
    perms(prowid,p,srowid,s) AS (SELECT prowid,p,srowid,s FROM prefixes JOIN suffixes),
    potentials AS (
        SELECT name,replace(replace(name,p||' ',''),' '||s,'') AS editedName, length(replace(replace(name,p||' ',''),' '||s,'')) AS l, p AS prefix, s AS suffix FROM channels JOIN perms WHERE instr(name,p||' ') OR instr(name,' '||s) ORDER BY name ASC , l DESC)
UPDATE channels SET editedName = (SELECT editedname FROM potentials WHERE potentials.name = channels.name AND potentials.l = (SELECT min(l) FROM potentials AS p WHERE potentials.name = p.name)) WHERE channels.name IN(SELECT name FROM potentials);
/* Show the channels after the UPDATE */
SELECT * FROM channels;
/* Should really tidy up the code above but!!!! */
/* Cleanup the Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS channels;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PrefixesAndSuffixesSetting;
```

- Note the above may not be the most efficient, it is coded rather to try to simplify understanding what it is doing.

Comment: Have to split the comment in 3 parts, sorry. First of all, thanks for this very detailed and informative answer. 2. I will need some days to check all, as i am off this weekend with no Android studio. 
Regarding first issue, in the dialog where the user adds the prefixes & suffixes he wants to have removed I give the user an advice that he should pay attention to use spaces for the prefixes and suffixes he is inserting.
And I read about regexp, but as i know i cant use it with room. Part2 ->

Comment: Referring to split the name in 3 columns: so every channel would have a fixed prefix and/or suffix (based on its name), where only those can be removed, do i understand that right? Then, assuming there is channel with name f.e. "abc de ChannelName XZ" and abc is saved as prefix for this channel. If the user adds "abc de" to his list of prefixes, it will not been removed or? So probably thats not a solution that would work for my case. Part3 ->

Comment: Second solution: Wouldnt it be better to use (in the AltChannels class) startsWith for p in prefixes and endsWith for s in suffixes, instead of contains? AltChannels contains Channels, and pre/suffixes contains each the list of all added pre/suffixes by the user, correct? Cant I simple add these both directly in the Channels Entity? I tought it would be easier to check if a channel name starts/ends with a prefix/suffix from a list of strings, and save the modified name as editedName. But it seems rather difficult :
) Could using multiple queries instead of only one be another approach?

Comment: Q1 yes every channel would have a prefix and suffix which could be an empty string, so uneditedname is prefix + channel + suffix and editedname is just channel.

Comment: Problem with the *abc de channelname XZ* may be the space between de and channel (a test you should undertake). I didn't go there. Yes AltChannelsm when constructed gets the list of prefixes and suffixes from the p_and_s table. This was done this way as you said that p_and_s was a table. So if a table you would have to build the strings from the table after extracting. Of course the answer is more about the techniques than specifics so is ripe for adaptation to suit, which could to adapt the Channels Entity.

Comment: The one query is multiple queries all in one. You could separate them out but to do them in 1 transaction (and thus reduce overheads) requires the separate queries AND a function to combine then with the `@Transaction` and `@Query("")` annotations, so much like `resolveAllChannelEditedNames()`. As previously said the answer is more about the techniques/ways than a specific fixed unadaptable solution. Time was also a consideration (i.e. the lack of time and thus the need to rush a little without overly concentrating and best of the best type thinking).

Comment: asking a question about another problem I just realised that I never answered you. Sorry for that, as you always give great answers and you are really helpfull. In this case I got back to the way I used in my question, as in the release version of my app it worked without problems and was also fast enought to not restrict the user experience. Your answers are surely helpful for others.. thank you anyway